# PulseAudio & Ubuntu 14.04: Audio source switches when using USB device

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio

We have this bug across ALL our Ubunut setups at work, home, everywhere. As soon as we use a USB audio card (approx 90% of all available audio cards are USB nowadays), PulseAudio and Ubuntu forget what sound source we selected in settings and after standby, let alone reboot, we have to reselect audio settings.

We have this bug for 2 years now and every suggestion, every workaround failed. We have opened bugs and told our story, but nobody fixes it.

Who would like to team up to fix this extremely annoying and long standing bug in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:
Launch **pavucontrol** from sound menu (pulseaudio volume control, install it if necessary).
Go to the "output devices" tab, and click the green "define as default" button that is near USB soundcard.